# How to improve the displaying of a multiband raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, multi-band

I have a multiband (WV3) satellite image that I'm displaying in false color (R=NIR, G=Red, B=Green) on QGIS 2.14. The quality of the results I'm getting via simply changing the band rendering in **Layer-> Properties -> Style -> Band rendering --> Render Type: Multiband color** are substantially different, and lower than using the [SCP-plugin](https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/semi-automatic-classification-plugin.html):

Regular rendering via layer properties:
[image]

Band rendering via SCP:
[image]

I need to do this programmatically via PyQGIS, so I can't use the plugin. I have also tried to play around with raster enhancement buttons but no success. Does anyone know how to improve the quality of band rendering?

**UPDATE** As pointed out by @user30184, the issue was the fact the max values were not updated in the band rendering (pressing the 'Load' button in the band rendering window). The problem remains - how to update the rendered min/max values via PyQGIS? My current code:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer() #An multiband (8 band) raster 

lyr.renderer().setRedBand(7)
lyr.renderer().setGreenBand(5)
lyr.renderer().setBlueBand(3)

if hasattr(lyr, "setCacheImage"):
    lyr.setCacheImage(None)
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

The 'Load' action that needs to be completed in PyQGIS:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with no success with raster enhancement buttons? Spread out first the "Load min/max values" menu and populate the min/max values.

Comment: That actually worked, thanks! I assumed it does this automatically from PyQGIS upon changing the band with `lyr.renderer().setRedBand(7)` , but it doesn't. Do you know what is the method I should call on the QgsMultiBandColorRenderer to do this in Python (equivalent to the 'Load' button in the interface)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution to updating the min/max values after changing band order using PyQGIS:

```
#Change Bands rendering
#5-3-2 = true color /// 7-5-3 = false color vegetation
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

bands=[7,5,3]
lyr.renderer().setRedBand(bands[0])
lyr.renderer().setGreenBand(bands[1])
lyr.renderer().setBlueBand(bands[2])

if hasattr(lyr, "setCacheImage"):
    lyr.setCacheImage(None)
lyr.triggerRepaint()

contrast = QgsRaster.ContrastEnhancementStdDev #OR: QgsRaster.ContrastEnhancementCumulativeCut
lyr.setContrastEnhancement(QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum, contrast, iface.mapCanvas().extent())
```